# Merge data based on nearest date R

Tags: r, date, merge, left-join

How do I jeft.join 2 data frames based on the nearest date? I currently have the script written so that it joins by the exact date, but I would prefer to do it by nearest date in case there is not an exact match.

This is what I currently have:

```
MASTER_DATABASE <- left_join(ptnamesMID, CTDB, by = c("LAST_NAME", "FIRST_NAME", "Measure_date" = "VISIT_DATE"))
```

Answer (score 6):

The rolling joins in the `data.table` have a parameter `roll = "nearest"` which does probably what the OP expects.

Unfortunately, the OP has failed to provide sample data so I had to make up my own sample data.

#### Create sample datasets

```
set.seed(123L)
dates <- seq(as.Date("2017-01-01"), as.Date("2017-12-31"), by = "1 day")
ptnamesMID <- data.frame(ID = 1:10, Measure_date = sample(dates, 10L))
CTDB <- data.frame(ID = sample.int(10, 30L, TRUE), VISIT_DATE = sample(dates, 30L, TRUE))
```

Here, `ID` is used in place of `LAST_NAME` and `FIRST_NAME` for simplification. `ptnamesMID` consists of 10 rows while `CTDB` has 30 rows of randomly sampled visit dates.

#### Rolling join

```
library(data.table)
# coerce to data.table and append join columns to preserve the original columns 
setDT(CTDB)[, join_date := VISIT_DATE]
setDT(ptnamesMID)[, join_date := Measure_date]
# rolling join
CTDB[ptnamesMID, on = .(ID, join_date), roll = "nearest"]
```

> ```
>     ID VISIT_DATE  join_date Measure_date
>  1:  1 2017-06-20 2017-04-15   2017-04-15
>  2:  2 2017-05-17 2017-10-14   2017-10-14
>  3:  3 2017-06-10 2017-05-29   2017-05-29
>  4:  4 2017-10-17 2017-11-16   2017-11-16
>  5:  5 2017-06-13 2017-12-06   2017-12-06
>  6:  6 2017-02-16 2017-01-17   2017-01-17
>  7:  7 2017-07-24 2017-07-09   2017-07-09
>  8:  8 2017-10-23 2017-12-28   2017-12-28
>  9:  9 2017-02-20 2017-07-16   2017-07-16
> 10: 10 2017-08-31 2017-06-12   2017-06-12
> ```

In `data.table` syntax, `CTDB[ptnamesMID, ...]` is equivalent to a left join of `ptnamesMID` with `CTDB`, i.e., all rows of of `ptnamesMID` are kept in the result set.

Comment: Excellent answer, I needed to do a similar task, and not only did it work, it is *fast*. By contrast `nearestTimeandID` ran for half an hour and still didn't finish.

Comment: @Stonecraft. Are you referring to `nearestTimeandID()` from the `bayesbio` package? This package was released on CRAN in 2016 and has not been updated since. `data.table` is designed for speed and memory efficiency. It is a pity that its potential seems to be overlooked, occassionally. For instance, *rolling join to nearest* became available in 2013.

Comment: I am. I knew about the efficiency of `data.table`, but I had no idea about the rolling join.

Answer (score 3):

Without an example it's hard to help your use case. I'd try out a package by David Robinson:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fuzzyjoin/fuzzyjoin.pdf

Here is the example for `interval_join`:

```
if (requireNamespace("IRanges", quietly = TRUE)) {
x1 <- data.frame(id1 = 1:3, start = c(1, 5, 10), end = c(3, 7, 15))
x2 <- data.frame(id2 = 1:3, start = c(2, 4, 16), end = c(4, 8, 20))
interval_inner_join(x1, x2)
# Allow them to be separated by a gap with a maximum:
interval_inner_join(x1, x2, maxgap = 1) # let 1 join with 2
interval_inner_join(x1, x2, maxgap = 20) # everything joins each other
# Require that they overlap by more than a particular amount
interval_inner_join(x1, x2, minoverlap = 3)
# other types of joins:
interval_full_join(x1, x2)
interval_left_join(x1, x2)
interval_right_join(x1, x2)
interval_semi_join(x1, x2)
interval_anti_join(x1, x2)
}
```